# Sum of columns of 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
static void Display (int[] [] array, int[] count)
{
    System.out.println ("\n\t Original Order");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        int count1 = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print (array [i] [j] + "\t");
            count1 = count1 + array [i] [j];
            count [i] = count [i] + array [j] [i];
        }
        System.out.print ("  " + count1);
        System.out.println ();
    }
    System.out.println ();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print (count [i] + "\t");
    }
}
```

If you initialize the array "count" as 4 long and all spots filled with 0 then write directly to the array "array" with variables. Then when you run this it will work except for the fact that the last column (up and down) is just a 0. It won't actually display a sum for the last column. Just wondering if anyone knows why it isn't working that'd be very helpful, thank you!!

Comment: `count [i] = count [i] + array [j] [i];` -> `count [j] = count [j] + array [i] [j];`

Comment: Nevermind, this fixed it!! Thank you soo much. I've been looking at it for 4 hours and haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have flipped your indexes in one section of the code:

```
count [i] = count [i] + array [j] [i];
```

I think you meant:

```
count [i] = count [i] + array [i] [j];
```

EDIT: Given your comment, the actual problem is that since you are iterating through columns by doing this:

```
count [i] = count [i] + array [j] [i];
```

...your variable `i` only goes to 3, when your array is 4 long.

Comment: I've tried to have it as count[i] = count [i] + array [i][j]; but it just calculates the rows instead.

Comment: So what do you suppose I do in order to fix the error? I've been looking at it for about 4 hours now and still haven't thought of anything.

Comment: Is your array dimensioned as [3] [4] or is it [4] [4]?

Comment: Nevermind, saka1029 helped me out. Thank you anyways

Comment: also it was int[][]array = new int [4][5];